# No exception thrown when connecting to an offline SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I try to access (open a connection to) an offline sql server instance (service turned off) from my web service, no exception is thrown, just a brief 5 sec timeout followed by return (I put the breakpoint way out in my controller, not sure what the connection object returns yet during the call to open).

I'm trying to simulate a scenario where the DB is not available to the webservice, and figured an exception would be thrown and I could just log the error.

Any suggestions on how to properly detect DB connection issues (I'm guessing I need to look to see what the connection object returns when calling open). It'd be nice to just have an exception bubble up though.

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a try.. catch block.

Comment: Webservice controller code that accesses DB is already wrapped in try/catch.

Comment: @Steve amusingly, I was about to say "try **removing** a try/catch block" (I'm guessing the connect exception is being swallowed)

Comment: If the error is in the initialization of the form, you wont see an error unless you put it in a try.. catch and then do something with it. Really my point was, how are we to help with ZERO code to look at? It could be anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection timeout will be thrown for sure unless your thread is being aborted before that by a web server timeout.  Placing a try/catch in your controller would certainly catch the DB connection timeout.

You should post code, as `SqlConnection.Open()` definitely would throw an exception but if you're using some other call/code to open the connection and it's getting swallowed then it is obviously difficult to determine a root cause.

My guess is that you are getting back a `Connection` object that is not connected, to check if it's connected:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{ 
  ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't break open the DB access layer code yet, b/c other exceptions are being thrown up to the controller's (like login errors) no problem. I'm checking into now though, thanks.

Comment: Ah man, I have like 3 repositories I use (direct object map to table, arbitrary sql command string, and stored-proc based one), and I forgot to remove the try/catch around one of em way back when I refactored my exception handling and logging. Thanks.